# Change a char in all records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

Trying to **replace a character** of a column within **all the Records** of a table,

Wanted to change '_' with ' '

Any snippets how doing that?

**Notes :**

1. This is the primary key of type `Nvarchar`
2. Database is SQL Server CE
3. using management studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to do that :

```
Update dbo.table
Set    col = replace(col, '_', '');
```

Where `col` is the name of the column that you need to manipulate ...

Comment: Hi and thanks, let me try it, having doubt weather it works or not in SQL CE.

Comment: I tried this :  Set    ProductCol = replace(ProductCol, '_', ''); ,and got this error :  A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = TblProd,Constraint name = idxProd ] , seems I should drop my index, remove any future probable duplicates, and then run it again , am I right could you give your suggestion on this ?

Comment: Yes, because when you update the column you create duplicate and the index doesn't allow that situation ...